# Will dtype affect Pandas calculation performance?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, optimization

Aside from memory usage and disk usage, will float16 computation **faster** than float32 computation in Pandas dataframe? If so, how much more performance should I expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

float16 computation ***MUCH SLOWER*** than float32, it is happening because there is no equivalent of float16 in c.

since python is based on c, as there is no equivalent of that in c, numpy created a method to perform for float16.

( float is a 32 bit IEEE 754 single precision Floating Point Number1 bit for the sign, (8 bits for the exponent, and 23* for the value), i.e. float has 7 decimal digits of precision)

Becacause of this( process making equivalent to work on float16) float16 is slower than float32 or float64

[Python Numpy Data Types Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15340781/python-numpy-data-types-performance). talks about it